# Next js multiple dynamic pages

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am using Next Js in my application. I know that we can create dynamic pages using `pages` folder, but i can not create a certain design for pages structure.
 What i want to achieve: I need to have the next paths in my application: `/user/pageAccordingUserIdWhichIsDymamicPage/userDataWhichIsStaticPage/anotherDynamicPage`.
 My question is, how the folder structure should look?
 Note: all paths are related to user, so i expect that the pages should be located in one page folder from `pages`.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using a feature known as dynamic routing. For more information see: https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes.

## Creating the Routes

For each dynamic route/url you wish to create follow the process below:

1. Divide the URL into different sections based on the '/' character.

> For example: "/users/roger/data" would be split to [users, roger, data].

2. For each section of the URL, create a folder with the corresponding name. If a certain part of the URL is dynamic, the name of the folder should be wrapped in square brackets- `[dynamicData]`.
3. Finally, create as many `index.js` files as you need. These files should be placed in the folders you created.

> For example, if you wanted the page /users/roger to work - you would go to your pages directory, users, roger, and put an index.js file there. Remember - that if you want 'roger' to be dynamic, you would create a dynamic folder like `[userName]` instead of roger.

## Retrieving the Data

You could then access the dynamic properties in each index.js file by acceding the router's query property. For example:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const Post = () => {
    const router = useRouter()
    const {userId, dynamic} = router.query

    return <p>
        userId: {userId} <br />
        dynamic: {dynamic}
    </p>
}

export default Post
```

You would obviously replace the `{userId, dynamic}` with the names you chose for the dynamic routes (i.e - the names of the folders).

(Example adapted from the link above)

Comment: each here `pages/[userId]/userData/[dynamic].js` i will have 3 separate page: userId, userData and dynamic.js?

Comment: You could. In every folder that you want a page to exist - simply create an 'index.js' file. 
For example if you wanted a page for the route: pages/[userId], then you would put an index.js file inside the [userId] folder.

Comment: how should look the page. structure for this example: `users/userIDDynamic/car/carIdDynamic` ?

Comment: pages/users/[userIDDynamic]/car/[carIdDynamic].js

Comment: @ Inbar Koursh, i tried but does not work. I need each page from the list to be a separate page, but it does not work. Could you help?

Comment: Hi, I clarified my post. Try and re-read it.

Answer (score 0):

In Next js your route endpoints are defined by the file name thus making it quick and easy to create a new route.

Now let's say that you want to create a route like this ***"/profile/:id"***
with **id** being your custom parameter.

To create a file with a custom parameter just surround your custom parameter with brackets like this **[id]**

You can also use the three dot syntax (like this **[...id])** to accept infinite unspecified dynamic pages.

I would suggest watching the video linked down below which really helped me get started with Next js.

[nextjs crash course](https://youtu.be/MFuwkrseXVE)

Comment: ok, but for example, can i create this path `pages/user/userId/userUpdate/userText` and in this way to have 4 separate pages like: 1. user (static page)2. userId (dynamic page) 3.userUpdate( static page) 4. userText(dynamic page) ?

Comment: This is the link to their docs https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes. As I mentioned in my answer you can use the '...' syntax. They specifically state  **Dynamic routes can be extended to catch all paths by adding three dots (...) inside the brackets. For example:

pages/post/[...slug].js matches /post/a, but also /post/a/b, /post/a/b/c and so on.** Let me know if you found this useful or need extra help.